# Easiest way to run python script with parameters on a web server

Tags: php, python, node.js, django

Thought this would be straightforward, but it's giving me a lot of trouble.  What's the simplest way to run a python script with params on a web server?  I've tried Node, but had a lot of trouble with spawning child processes, tried PHP but ran into a similar problem and just couldn't get `exec` to work for even the simplest script.  Just spent a while trying Django, but that turned out to be far too involved.  How can I do this without re-inventing the wheel?

For example, take the following request:

```
www.example.com/someprogram?foo=bar&bar=baz
```

And render the output from a script run with those params:

```
python someprogram.py foo bar
```

Comment: Look at using the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) library.

Answer (score 0):

Try [bottle](https://bottlepy.org/), a micro web framework:

someprogram.py:

```
def f(foo, bar):
    return "foo: {}, bar: {}"format(foo, bar)
```

server.py:

```
from bottle import route, run
import someprogram


@route('/')
def home():
    return someprogram.f(request.query.foo, request.query.bar)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run(debug=True, reloader=True)
```

To run:

```
pip install bottle
python server.py
```

Use [`subprocess.check_output()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) to spawn a process if you don't want to import `someprogram.py`.

Comment: (BTW - Python can be used as a cgi enabled server, but it is considered obsolete and not safe: https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html#http.server.CGIHTTPRequestHandler )